# HEALTHCHECK of a Docker container running Celery tasks?

Tags: docker, celery

I know one of the ways to check health for Docker container is using the commmand

```
HEALTHCHECK CMD curl --fail http://localhost:3000/ || exit 1
```

But in case of workers there is no such URL to hit , How to check the container's health in that case ?

Answer (score 41):

The `celery inspect ping` command comes in handy, as it does a whole trip: it sends a "ping" task on the broker, workers respond and celery fetches the responses.

Assuming your app is named `tasks.add`, you may ping all your workers:

```
/app $ celery inspect ping -A tasks.add
-> celery@aa7c21dd0e96: OK
        pong
-> celery@57615db15d80: OK
        pong
```

With `aa7c21dd0e96` being the Docker hostname, and thus available in `$HOSTNAME`.

To ping a single node, you would have to run:

```
celery inspect ping -A tasks.add -d celery@$HOSTNAME
```

Here, *d* stands for *destination*.

The line to add to your Dockerfile:

```
HEALTHCHECK CMD celery inspect ping -A tasks.add -d celery@$HOSTNAME
```

---

Sample outputs:

```
/app $ celery inspect ping -A tasks.add -d fake_node
Error: No nodes replied within time constraint.
/app $ echo $?
69
```

Unhealthy if the node does not exist or does not reply

```
/app $ celery inspect ping -A tasks.add -d celery@$HOSTNAME
-> celery@d39b3d31cc13: OK
        pong
/app $ echo $?
0
```

Healthy when the node replies `pong`.

```
/app $ celery inspect ping -d celery@$HOSTNAME
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    raise socket.error(last_err)
OSError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
/app $ echo $?
1
```

Unhealthy when the broker is not available - I removed the app, so it tries to connect to a local AMPQ and fails
This might not suit your needs, the broker is unhealthy, not the worker.

Comment: with SQS, how do you do? you can't use the result with sqs and celery http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/getting-started/brokers/sqs.html#broker-sqs

Comment: I believe "Assuming your app is named tasks.add" it's a confusing assumption: an app should not live in a module named `tasks`, if you want to minimize confusion.

Comment: For SQS, you can specify the pidfile using `--pidfile /opt/celery/celery_pid` and check that the process is still running using `kill -0 $(cat /opt/celery/celery_pid)`. Got this from the guy that runs masterpoint.io.

Comment: @SomeGuyOnAComputer nice tip on using `kill -0` thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The below example snippet, derived from that posted by @PunKeel, is applicable for those looking to implement health check in `docker-compose.yml` which could be used through `docker-compose` or `docker stack deploy`.

```
worker:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: myimage
    links:
        - rabbitmq
    restart: always
    command: celery worker --hostname=%h --broker=amqp://rabbitmq:5672
    healthcheck:
        test: celery -b amqp://rabbitmq:5672 inspect ping -d celery@$$HOSTNAME
        interval: 30s
        timeout: 10s
        retries: 3
```

Notice the extra `$` in the command, so that `$HOSTNAME` actually gets passed into the container. I also didn't use the `-A` flag.

Ideally, rabbitmq should also have its own health check, perhaps with `curl guest:guest@localhost:15672/api/overview`, since docker wouldn't be able to discern if worker is down or the broker is down with `celery inspect ping`.

--
edit:

please also check out the solution provided by `SomeGuyOnAComputer`
on using `kill -0 $PID` to check if PID is alive.

Comment: In case you are using authentication, you can provide username and password by writing `user:pass@rabbitmq:5672`.
 
You can even use environment variables you set yourself for your application like, `celery inspect ping -b amqp://$${RABBITMQ_USER}:$${RABBITMQ_PASS}@$${RABBITMQ_HOST}:5672 -d celery@$$HOSTNAME`

Comment: On Celery 5.2.3: `Error: No such option: -b`

Comment: The order needs to be changed: `celery -b amqp://rabbitmq:5672 inspect ping`

Comment: updated healthheck test command per @Mart!

Comment: Regarding `RabbitMQ`, `curl` might not be available in the Alpine version and/or the RabbitMQ management plugin might be deactivated: the best solution is to use a command similar to `rabbitmq-diagnostics -q status && rabbitmq-diagnostics -q check_local_alarms`. See the doc: https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-diagnostics.8.html

Answer (score 4):

For celery 5.2.3 I used `celery -A [celery app name] status` for the health check. This is how my docker-compose file looks like

```
worker:
      build: .
      healthcheck:
        test: celery -A app.celery_app status
        interval: 10s
        timeout: 10s
        retries: 10
      volumes:
          - ./app:/app
      depends_on:
        - broker
        - redis
        - database
```

Comment: Thanks! But exit codes other than `0` and `1` correspond to an undefined behaviour, so here's a slight improvement: `celery -A [celery app name] status || exit 1`. Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck and https://www.atatus.com/blog/health-check-command-in-docker/

Answer (score 1):

Landed on this question looking for a health check for Celery workers as part of an Airflow setup (Airflow 2.3.4, Celery 5.2.7), which I eventually figured out. This is a very specific use case of the original question, but might still be useful for some:

```
# docker-compose.yml

  worker:
      image: ...
      hostname: local-worker
      entrypoint: airflow celery worker
      ...
      healthcheck:
        test: [ "CMD-SHELL", 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"' ]
        interval: 5s
        timeout: 10s
        retries: 10
      restart: always
      ...
```

I got inspiration from [Airflow's quick-start Docker Compose](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/docker-compose.yaml).

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that:

```
...
healthcheck:
    test: sh -c 'celery -A your_celery_module inspect ping'
    ...
```

Your log file will have a similar ping log:

> [2023-05-05 11:18:47,309: DEBUG/MainProcess] pidbox received method ping() [reply_to:{'exchange': 'reply.celery.pidbox', 'routing_key': '8195241f-122a-3dc4-9841-739f55804b82'} ticket:bada7609-ce6b-499a-b3c2-c80911e0fe09]

Also, you might want to check it yourself in an already-running container. In that case, it will look something like this:

[image: celery ping output]

Answer (score 0):

To configure a HEALTHCHECK for a Docker container running Celery tasks and ensure another container depends on its health status:

In your Docker Compose file:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  celery:
    # Celery container config
    healthcheck:
      test: celery inspect ping
      interval: 1m
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
      start_period: 1m

  dependent_container:
    # Dependent container config
    depends_on:
      celery:
        condition: service_healthy
```

This sets up a health check for the `celery` container using `celery inspect ping`. 
The `dependent_container` depends on `celery` with `condition: service_healthy`, ensuring it starts only when `celery` is healthy.